# Solving n Equations Ax = b where A contains nonzero elements at top right corner and the bottom left corner too

Tags: matrix-equations, mathematical-physics

If a matrix A is like tridiagonal but contains nonzero elements at top right corner and the bottom left corner, how to solve equations like Ax = b?

I was thinking to use the Thomas algorithm but how to make the matrix tridiagonal?

Thanks!